# Concatenar um link dentro de um atributo href com uma variável?

Tags: javascript, html

Queria saber como eu faço para concatenar um link dentro de um atributo `href` com uma variável?
Observação tem que ser algo *'inline'*.
Eu uso uma plataforma que não me deixa usar scripts dentro da página por isso o motivo do inline.

Exemplo:

```
var teste = [x];
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://websro.correios.com.br/sro_bin/txect01$.QueryList?P_LINGUA=001&P_COD_UNI=',teste)" target"_blank">vai</a>
```

A saída deveria ser:

```
http://websro.correios.com.br/sro_bin/txect01$.QueryList?P_LINGUA=001&P_COD_UNI=[x]
```

Meu código está errado na organização dos elementos ou aspas no lugar errado então desconsidere essa parte. Preciso de uma sugestão de como eu montaria isso.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Defina uma variável global e use o operador `+` para concatenar:

```
<script>
var teste = "blabla";
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://websro.correios.com.br/sro_bin/txect01$.QueryList?P_LINGUA=001&P_COD_UNI=' + teste)" target"_blank">vai</a>
```

[Demonstração](http://jsfiddle.net/eMuEq/)

A concatenação irá ocorrer no momento do clique.

Comment: Consegue colocar um exemplo no JSFiddle?

Comment: Sim, editei a resposta com o link

Comment: Sua resposta foi a que mais se aproximou, então eu considerarei ela como certa. Obrigado @bfavaretto

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar um input hidden e setar um value algo como:

```
<input type="hidden" name="teste" id="name" value="qualquer-valor"/>
```

Ai você pega o value e concatena no seu link algo como:

```
onclick="window.open('http://websro.correios.com.br/sro_bin/txect01$.QueryList?P_LINGUA=001&P_COD_UNI=' + document.getElementById('teste').value)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o "eval", mas seu uso não é recomendado por questões de segurança.

Assim:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var teste = 'blah';
    </script>
    <a href="#" onclick="eval('window.open(\'http://websro.correios.com.br/sro_bin/txect01$.QueryList?P_LINGUA=001&P_COD_UNI=\' + teste)')" target"_blank">vai</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Cuidado com o uso do eval. Como disse, ele traz falhas de segurança mas, como você disse que o código tem que ser inline, isso resolve.

Comment: não pensei nesse método mas parece ser interessante essa informação vai direto par um email, sera que pode ter eventuais problemas?

Comment: Não precisa usar eval para fazer uma simples concatenação!

Comment: @bfavaretto hahaha, você tem toda razão, viajei na maionese! =D